# UIManagedDocument : block passed to completion handler never gets called

Tags: ios, core-data, uimanageddocument

Hi, here's the code I created to handle my UIManagedDocument in JIPManagedDocument.m :

```
+(JIPManagedDocument *)sharedManagedDocument
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    NSURL *url = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
    url = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"DemoDocument"];
    _sharedManagedDocument = [[JIPManagedDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:url];
    });

   return _sharedManagedDocument;
}

-(void)performBlockWithDocument:(void (^)(JIPManagedDocument * managedDocument))block
{
    void (^completionBlock) (BOOL) = ^(BOOL success) 
    {
        if (success)
        {
          block(self);
          NSLog(@"COULD PERFORM BLOCK WITH ManagedDocument");
        }
        else
        {
          NSLog(@"COULDNT PERFORM BLOCK WITH ManagedDocument");
        }
        self.openingDocument = NO;
    };

    if (self.documentState == UIDocumentStateNormal)
    {
        completionBlock(YES);
    }

    else if (! self.openingDocument)
    {
       self.openingDocument = YES;

       if ( ! [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[self.fileURL path]] )
       {
           [self        saveToURL:self.fileURL
                 forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating
               completionHandler:completionBlock];
        }


        else if (self.documentState == UIDocumentStateClosed)
        {
           [self openWithCompletionHandler:completionBlock];
        }
    }  
}
```

And then when I try to call the method like this :

```
[[JIPManagedDocument sharedManagedDocument] performBlockWithDocument:^(JIPManagedDocument *managedDocument)
 {
     //Do something
 }];
```

The `//Do something` part never gets executed.

Any help would be very appreciated, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

The block you pass as parameter, that is the one that will call the //Do something. You only call it there :

```
if (success)
{
     block(self);
     NSLog(@"COULD PERFORM BLOCK WITH ManagedDocument");
}
```

Are you sure that, this condition is fulfilled ?

Comment: Well in what cases, openwithcompletionhandler could fail ? ------Here's my singleton method in the same.m file :                              +(JIPManagedDocument *)sharedManagedDocument
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        NSURL *url = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
        url = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"DemoDocument"];
        _sharedManagedDocument = [[JIPManagedDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:url];
    });
    
    return _sharedManagedDocument;
}